# Should all the fields in a GlobalSettings modelling class be static ( C# centric )?

Tags: c#, static, singleton, settings, field

The idea is that the ApplicationSettings class will get some default values from a configuration / resource file and later on some but not all from those settings will be applied to UserSettings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only instance fields in such a class, and make the whole class a Singleton if needed (although be careful not to expose it globally - [singletons are evil](http://www.riedquat.de/prog/singletonsAreEvil)).

Static fields cannot be serialized (which is important for a settings class). Second thing, by having instance fields, you can easily pass different instances of settings to different parts of your app. And the important point is to **pass** the settings to the rest of the application, not to make them globally visible so that every object can access them.